# C# - Bind CommandParameter to the "DataContext" of a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'd like to be able to bind the `CommandParameter` of a `Button` to be the current `ListViewItem`. Here's my XAML :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Playlists" ItemsSource="{Binding Playlists, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="5">
                <Button x:Name="btnPlayPlaylist" Content="Play" Command="{Binding Path=PlayPlaylistCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I click the `btnPlayPlaylist` button, I'd like to be able to receive in my ViewModel the corresponding playlist. Either by getting it's index in my `List<Playlist>` or the `Playlist` object directly.

Is their any way of doing that ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is.
You are using a command, in this case you should define a parameter for it in order for the code behind to have access to the Model in which the button was located.

So briefly:

```
<Button x:Name="btnPlayPlaylist" Content="Play" Command="{Binding Path=PlayPlaylistCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

The command parameter is now the whole Playlist (the whole DataContext of the button). 
In code behind for Command_Executed, access the parameter like so:

```
var playlist = e.Parameter as Playlist;
```

here I assumed that your DataType is Playlist.

NOTE: however there is another approach to this without the use of commands! Just add an event handler for the button and specify a Tag on it.

```
<Button x:Name="btnPlayPlaylist" Content="Play" Click="button_Click" Tag="{Binding}" />
```

and then in code behind:

```
var playlist = (sender as Button).Tag as Playlist;
```

remember always to Cast the Tag and sender and parameter

Comment: Thanks ! I never though it'd be so simple :P

Comment: ;) With WPF a lot of things are easier.

Answer (score 2):

To send current `DataContext` as `CommandParameter` you do

```
<Button ... CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

Or

```
<Button ... CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}">
```

Comment: @Dpedrinha in this case there's no difference but if you would like to add Converter for example then you need to explicitly set Path and then you need to use second option.